# Haskell. How to implement a custom monad transformer using GADT?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I'm trying to learn about monad transformers by implementing my own. The code
compiles if I use `newType DummyT m x y z = DummyT { runDummyT :: m (Dummy x y z) }`
but not if I use GADT. However I need to use GADT but it seems to be more
difficult. I get this error:

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘m’   
Expected a type, but ‘m’ has kind ‘* -> *’                                              
In the first argument of ‘DummyT’, namely ‘m’                                          
In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘(DummyT m x y)`
```

I get the same error for the applicative and monad instances.
Why do I get this error? Any help is appreciated.

my monad:

```
instance Monad (Dummy x y) where
  return = Return
  (>>=) = Bind

data Dummy x y z where
  Return :: z -> Dummy x y z
  Bind :: Dummy x y z -> (z -> Dummy x y q) -> Dummy x y q
```

transformer attempt:

```
instance Monad m => Functor (DummyT m x y) where
  fmap = liftM

instance Monad m => Applicative (DummyT m x y) where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad m => Monad (DummyT m x y) where
  return = Return
  (>>=) = Bind

data DummyT m x y z where
  Return :: z -> DummyT m x y z
  Bind :: DummyT m x y z -> (z -> DummyT m x y q) -> DummyT m x y q
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
newType DummyT m x y z = DummyT { runDummyT :: m (Dummy x y z) }
```

the kind of `m` is obviously `* -> *` since `m` is applied to a type.

In

```
data DummyT m x y z where
  Return :: z -> DummyT m x y z
  Bind :: DummyT m x y z -> (z -> DummyT m x y q) -> DummyT m x y q
```

`m` is unused, so GHC infers kind `*`, since that's the simplest. It could have made this poly-kinded, perhaps, but did not.

If you want another kind, explicitly ask for it:

```
data DummyT (m :: * -> *) x y z where
  Return :: z -> DummyT m x y z
  Bind :: DummyT m x y z -> (z -> DummyT m x y q) -> DummyT m x y q
```

I wonder, though, if not using `m` here makes any sense.

Comment: `*` is on its slow match into oblivion. Better to import `Data.Kind` and use `Type`.

Comment: Thank you, now it compiles. Could you please explain why `m` might not be needed?

Comment: @datamoose You didn't use it in the types of `Return` and `Bind` except as an argument of `DummyT`. At no point we can read `m (some type)` as we did in the `newtype` definition.

Comment: @datamoose, I suspect that to make this a monad transformer you'll want to add a constructor `Lift :: m a -> DummyT m x y a`. Better first to rearrange your type parameters: `DummyT x y m a`. That'll let you write `instance MonadTrans (DummyT x y) where lift = Lift`.